# XenApp will not "stream" published applications, but will run "installed applications"

Tags: citrix, xenapp

I have setup a XenApp 6.0 environment.  I can publish and run "installed applications" such as Windows Write and these run perfectly on the client PC.  However, when I attempt to publish a "streamed application", it will not run on the client PC.  I can log in to the web interface and I can see the published "streamed application" but when I attempt to run it, the icon displays the animated circle as if it were attempting to start, but it never starts; the animated circle just goes away and nothing happens.  This is the case with Microsoft Office 2007 applications, Adobe Acrobat Standard, and another PDF reader that I attempted to "stream" to the client.  I have rebooted the server (and the licensing server and web interface server), deleted and re-added the published applications, etc.

I don't receive any error messages or indications in the event viewer on my XenApp server.  As far as I can tell, this isn't a licensing issue either, as I have a XenApp Enterprise license.  In addition, when I log in to the XenApp server, I don't see myself as "connected" on the "streamed apps" when I attempt to run them.

Comment: What does the event viewer on the Web Interface server say? Have you tried re profiling them?

Answer (score 0):

If your streaming to client desktops fail, the XenApp Plugin for Streamed Apps running on XenApp can virtualize the application on the client device. Alternatively, you can opt to always stream applications to a XenApp server instead of desktops and have XenApp virtualize applications on client devices that have the XenApp Plugins for both Hosted and Streamed Apps 
installed. This can ease delivery of applications to servers in your farm

I'd also consider reading over [THIS](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX116416) document from Citrix in case you meet any other things they outline in the streaming app Readme document that you haven't disclosed in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to offline plugin installed over the online plugin. (http://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/additional-client-software/offline-plug-in-674.html)

Be aware you can install the old offline plugin over the new receiver, as the offline plugin is getting more retiered.

You can see if the plug in is there as it will install the radecache application to pre-cache the offline application. (in c:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\Streaming Client)

That tool can help to diagnose: [Application Streaming Launch Tool](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX126674/)